# Vim consolidating `;` into `n`

Tags: vim

I've been reworking some of key bindings that represent a friction in my workflow. One of the major annoyances for me are `;` and `,`, which perform jumps after character search (f, t, F, T).

So I thought, is it possible to consolidate with search (`/foo<CR>`) jumps, the latter being `n` and `N` respectively.

I'd like to do so in a fashion, that wouldn't break anything. I have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: assume you made it work. you did a `/foo<cr>`, then did a `fx`,  now you pressed `n`, can you tell what do you expect? the next `x` in the line? or the next `foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than consolidating these into `n`, I'd recommend taking a look at [clever-f](https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim)